Plural vs. singular: „The team realizes they might be a target“

The team realizes they might be a target.

I recently came across this sentence in an episode of a TV show I watched. It‘s on one of the big streaming platforms and it‘s quite a big TV show, so I  naturally assumed that the sentence is correct or at least written or checked by a native speaker.
However, I‘m unable to understand why the sentence was written this way and I‘m now wondering if it‘s at all correct.
Specifically, I thought it would have to be either

The team realize they might be a target.

or

The team realizes it might be a target.

but not a mixture of the two.
I have read some of the other questions on this site regarding collective nouns being treated as singular or plural. I have also understood that it might be different in American English vs British English, but this just seems inconsistent to me.
Can someone help?

Mixing up singular and plural like this is very common, especially in less 'academic' (but still not informal) writing. if the team knows they should be talking to customers but are struggling to set up calls, that's where I'd provide help, the team knows they will face challenging road games in the coming weeks, if the team wishes they can amend or summarise principles based on their context, the team hopes they have "solved some of the inherent problems" - I would avoid it if it bothers you, (purists will notice it) but it is not a big deal, e.g. in a blog.

Thank you, that makes total sense. It didn‘t bother me so much as confuse me, so I was very hesitant to add that to my feel for the English language.
If you add that as an answer I‘ll mark it as the accepted one :)

You are crossing the line that separates 'English as taught to second language learners', with all its 'rules', and the real language as used in everyday life by real people.

Mixing up singular and plural like this is very common, especially in less 'academic' (but still not informal) writing.

If the team knows they should be talking to customers but are
struggling to set up calls, that's where I'd provide help.
The team knows they will face challenging road games in the coming
weeks.
If the team wishes they can amend or summarise principles based on
their context.
The team hopes they have "solved some of the inherent problems".

I would avoid it if it bothers you, (purists will notice it) but it is not a big deal, e.g. in a blog.


The team realizes they might be a target.

The OP’s right that it should be either realize they or realizes it.  The speaker probably had wanted to use the singular for the collective noun but decided halfway to use they, thinking that it isn’t the
right pronoun for people.
